# CSS to display 2 boxes on one row with multiple rows

Tags: css

I am trying to get the design presented in the image below or at least something similar. I am working in symfony 4, without bootstrap, only plain css. The boxes are displayed through a form loop in twig.

[image: design wanted]

These is my twig template:

```
        {% for contact in contacts %}
        <div class="client">
            {% if contact.giftCheck %}
                <p class="bold">{{ contact.giftCheck.beneficiaryUser.firstName }}
                {{ contact.giftCheck.beneficiaryUser.lastName }}</p>
                <p class="bold">{{ contact.giftCheck.orderItem.box }}</p>
                <p class="bold">{{ contact.chosenFormula }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        <a class="edit_btn">Accepter</a>
        <a class="edit_btn">Refuser</a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

These is my css so far:

```
.client{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: fit-content;
    block-size: fit-content;
    border: solid #000000 1px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

and how it looks like curently:
[image]

Comment: You may use a flex display from the parent : example overriding your styles : https://jsfiddle.net/uo9m4yaq/

Answer (score 1):

The community provided the following answer, which helps me:

```css
.client {
  width: fit-content;
  block-size: fit-content;
  border: solid #000000 1px;
  padding: 15px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2em;
}

.columns .client {
  width: auto;
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
  <div class="client">
    Client
  </div>
</div>
```